# How to have Python package not require import package.package

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

**tl;dr** - My python package requires `import package.package` instead of working with just `import package`. How do I get it to work with the latter?

---

I am trying to set up my first python package and am running into some issues with the import part of the process.

My python package file setup looks like this on my computer:

```
my-package
 - build
 - dist
 - package
 - package.egg-info
 - LICENSE
 - README.md
 - Setup.py
```

Inside `package` is the following:

```
__init__.py
package.py
```

`__init__.py` reads `name = 'package'`, and `package.py` contains all of the content of the package.

EDIT: I have attempted using various different versions of `__init__.py`, including adding `import package`, `import package.package`, or `import package.package as package` below the line `name = 'package'`, but all of resulted in the same issue.

Using the [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) tutorial, I've been able to get my package upload to TestPyPi, but when I install the package to my computer, none of the functions/methods are available, and when I run "import package" and do `help(package)`, I get the following:

```
Help on package package:

NAME
    package

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    package

DATA
    name = 'package'

FILE
    url/to/package
```

When I run `import package.package` and `help(package)`, I can access the methods/functions, and get the expected help text for the package's content.

My question is, how to I configure the package file on my computer in such a way that once it is upload to TestPyPi and then downloaded, `import package` works, instead of needing to run `import package.package`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `import package`, you can access names in `package/__init__.py` as `package.foo`.

So, inside `__init__.py`, if you import all the necessary functions/variables/etc from `package.py`, those names will be visible to clients that just `import package`.

So, if you have this in `package/__init__.py`:

```
from .package import (foo, bar, baz)
```

Then in your other code you can do this:

```
from package import foo
```

And you dont have to worry about `from package.package import foo`.

Comment: The way I've designed it, everything that is in the package is in the `package` file, including the help text, so doing `from .package import (all content in the package)` would be problematic. Am I misunderstanding this or is there another way to go about it?

Comment: You could use `from .package import *`.  Or just rename `package.py` to `__init__.py`.